# Laravel protect routes from users that are not admin

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have certain routes that I need to protect from users that are not admin.

For example

```
http://myapp.com/clients
```

returns all the clients but is only for the administrator.

However

```
 http://myapp.com/client/treutel_breitenberg
```

Should be available to them if they are logged in.

What is the best way to achieve this

Comment: You can use middleware for this case

Comment: yes https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need roles and a middleware, and there are many ways to do it. First you need to create an admin role, so some of your routes will only be available for someone who has the admin role. For that you can follow this laracasts tutorial : https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/16

You can also use a plugin to manage roles, like Zizaco's Entrust, it's built-up good, tested by a lot of users and easy to use : https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Next, to answer your question for the routes you can proceed like that :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
      Route::get('/your-path', 'YourController@yourMethod')->name('yourRouteName');

    }
}
```

Any route within these two groups will need to be authenticated as admin and will return 'admin' prefix in your route, like so : www.yourwebsite.com/admin/your-path

If you don't use a plugin, you'll need to create your middleware to handle admins only.

Comment: I only have 2 roles, you are either a super admin or not but is good to know. Thanks.